# About value in context (applied in Monad)

Tags: haskell

I have a small question about value in context.

- Take `Just 'a'`, so the value in context of type `Maybe` in this case is `'a'`
- Take `[3]`, so value in context of type `[a]` in this case is `3`
- And if you apply the monad for `[3]` like this: `[3] >>= \x -> [x+3]`, it means you assign `x` with value `3`. It's ok.

But now, take `[3,2]`, so what is the value in the context of type `[a]`?. And it's so strange that if you apply monad for it like this:

```
[3,4] >>= \x -> x+3
```

It got the correct answer `[6,7]`, but actually we don't understand what is *x* in this case. You can answer, ah *x* is 3 and then 4, and *x* feeds the function 2 times and concat as `Monad` does: `concat (map f xs)` like this:

```
[3,4] >>= concat (map f x)
```

So in this case, `[3,4]` will be assigned to the *x*. It means wrong, because `[3,4]` is not a value. `Monad` is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the `concat` bit. And certainly, `Monad` is not wrong, it just works in a way you apparently don't expect!

Comment: As definition of monad, (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b. And the instance of Monad [] is xs >>= f = concat (map f xs). Function f will take a normal value and turns it into a value with context. In the function concat (map f xs), xs is a list (this is not a value, it is a value in context). I mean, if you apply [2,3] in monad, in function concat (map f xs), xs is still [2,3], it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is focusing too much on the values. A monad is a type constructor, and as such not concerned with how many and what kinds of values there are, but *only* the context.

A `Maybe a` can be an `a`, or nothing. Easy, and you correctly observed that.

An `Either String a` is either some `a`, or alternatively some information in form of a `String` (e.g. why the calculation of `a` failed).

Finally, `[a]` is an unknown number of `a`s (or none at all), that may have resulted from an ambiguous computation, or one giving multiple results (like a quadratic equation).

---

Now, for the interpretation of `(>>=)`, it is helpful to know that the essential property of a monad (how it is defined by category theorists) is

```
join :: m (m a) -> m a.
```

Together with `fmap`, `(>>=)` can be written in terms of `join`.

What `join` means is the following: *A context, put in the same context again, still has the same resulting behavior* (for this monad).

This is quite obvious for `Maybe (Maybe a)`: Something can essentially be `Just (Just x)`, or `Nothing`, or `Just Nothing`, which provides the same information as `Nothing`. So, instead of using `Maybe (Maybe a)`, you could just have `Maybe a` and you wouldn't lose any information. That's what `join` does: it converts to the "easier" context.

`[[a]]` is somehow more difficult, but not much. You essentially have multiple/ambiguous results out of multiple/ambiguous results. A good example are the roots of a fourth-degree polynomial, found by solving a quadratic equation. You first get two solutions, and out of each you can find two others, resulting in four roots.

But the point is, it doesn't matter if you speak of an ambiguous ambiguous result, or just an ambiguous result. You could just always use the context "ambiguous", and transform multiple levels with `join`.

And here comes what `(>>=)` does for lists: it applies ambiguous functions to ambiguous values:

```
squareRoots :: Complex -> [Complex] 

fourthRoots num = squareRoots num >>= squareRoots
```

can be rewritten as

```
fourthRoots num = join $ squareRoots `fmap` (squareRoots num)
-- [1,-1,i,-i]    <-  [[1,-1],[i,-i]]  <-       [1,-1] <- 1
```

since all you have to do is to find all possible results for each possible value.

This is why `join` is `concat` for lists, and in fact

```
m >>= f == join (fmap f) m
```

must hold in any monad.

A similar interpretation can be given to `IO`. A computation with side-effects, which can also have side-effects (`IO (IO a)`), is in essence *just something with side-effects*.

Comment: Geek out alert: I realise this is going to count as taking the maths too seriously, but if it's `pol` short for polynomial, it's OK to have roots, but then you can't have roots of roots and even then `getFourthOrderRoots` would in general supply up to four items, not just two. If you mean roots of numbers rather than of polynomials (and the data suggests you do), then you need Double or Complex, and either fourth roots of negative numbers don't exist or there are four of them. Sorry. You did say not to take the maths seriously, but I couldn't help myself!

Comment: You're totally right. It was just the first best example I could think of (I had this in calculus today), and I didn't really want to mess up the nice one-liner. I'd be glad to find something more accurate. Does anybody have a good idea?

Comment: You could use `getIntegerSquareRoots`, call it `nums` not `pols`, and make your initial `nums` `[1,16]` which gives `[[-1,1],[-4,4]]`, joining down to `[-1,1,-4,4]`, then on second application of `getIntegerSquareRoots` to `[[],[-1,1],[],[-2,2]]`, which joins down to `[-1,1,-2,2]`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to take the word "context" quite broadly.

A common way of interpreting a list of values is that it represents an indeterminate value, so [3,4] represents a value which is three or four, but we don't know which (perhaps we just know it's a solution of x^2 - 7x + 12 = 0).

If we then apply f to that, we know it's 6 or 7 but we still don't know which.

Another example of an indeterminate value that you're more used to is 3. It could mean 3::Int or 3::Integer or even sometimes 3.0::Double.  It feels easier because there's only one symbol representing the indeterminate value, whereas in a list, all the possibilities are listed (!).

If you write

```
asum = do
   x <- [10,20]
   y <- [1,2]
   return (x+y)
```

You'll get a list with four possible answers: [11,12,21,22]
That's one for each of the possible ways you could add x and y.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the values that are in the context, it's the types.

`Just 'a' :: Maybe Char` --- `Char` is in a `Maybe` context.

`[3, 2] :: [Int]` --- `Int` is in a `[]` context.

Whether there is one, none or many of the `a` in the `m a` is beside the point.

**Edit:** Consider the type of `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

You give the example `Just 3 >>= (\x->Just(4+x))`. But consider `Nothing >>= (\x->Just(4+x))`. There is no value in the context. But the type is in the context all the same.

It doesn't make sense to think of `x` as necessarily being a single value. `x` has a single type. If we are dealing with the `Identity` monad, then `x` will be a single value, yes. If we are in the `Maybe` monad, `x` may be a single value, or it may never be a value at all. If we are in the list monad, `x` may be a single value, or not be a value at all, or be various different values... but what it is not is the list of all those different values.

Your other example --- `[2, 3] >>= (\x -> x + 3)` --- `[2, 3]` is *not* passed to the function. `[2, 3] + 3` would have a type error. `2` is passed to the function. And so is `3`. The function is invoked twice, gives results for both those inputs, and the results are combined by the `>>=` operator. `[2, 3]` is not passed to the function.

Comment: Look, if you take "Just 3" and apply it in a function f like (\x -> Just (4+x)), such as        Just 3 >>= (\x->Just(4+x))        and you got (Just 7). So the value in this context is 3. Now, back to the question, when you apply [2,3] to the function \x -> [x+3], so what is the x here? [2,3] >>= (\x -> [x+3]) = concat (map (\x->[x+3]) [2,3]).   You see, it means [2,3] is applied in the function, so the value in the context is the same as original. What's the point here?

Comment: You said Nothing >>= (\x->Just(4+x)), there is no value in the context? Let's have a look at the declaration of monad type Maybe for the case Nothing:  Nothing >>= f = Nothing   .And it means, the function doesn't care about the input, doesn't handle with the input, just returns Nothing value if the input is Nothing. Anyway, Nothing is actually a value in the context.

Comment: Earlier you said that if I fed in `Just 3` then the value in that context was `3`. Now you say that if I feed in `Nothing` then the value in that context is `Nothing`. Those statements can't both be true: the "values in the context" have different types!

Answer (score 0):

"context" is one of my favorite ways to think about monads. But you've got a slight misconception.

> Take Just 'a', so the value in context of type Maybe in this case is 'a'

Not quite. You keep saying `the value in context`, but there is not always a value "inside" a context, or if there is, then it is not necessarily the only value. It all depends on *which* context we are talking about.

The `Maybe` context is the context of "nullability", or potential absence. There might be something there, or there might be `Nothing`. There is no value "inside" of `Nothing`. So the maybe context might have a value inside, or it might not. If I give you a `Maybe Foo`, then you cannot assume that there is a `Foo`. Rather, you must assume that it is a `Foo` *inside the context where there might actually be `Nothing` instead*. You might say that something of type `Maybe Foo` is a *nullable `Foo`*.

> Take [3], so value in context of type [a] in this case is 3

Again, not quite right. A list represents a *nondeterministic* context. We're not quite sure *what* "the value" is supposed to be, or if there is one at all. In the case of a singleton list, such as `[3]`, then yes, there is just one. But one way to think about the list `[3,4]` is as *some* unobservable value which we are not quite sure what it is, but we are certain that it `3` or that it is `4`. You might say that something of type `[Foo]` is a *nondeterministic `Foo`*.

---

> `[3,4] >>= \x -> x+3`

This is a type error; not quite sure what you meant by this.

> So in this case, `[3,4]` will be assigned to the x. It means wrong, because `[3,4]` is not a value. Monad is wrong.

You totally lost me here. Each instance of `Monad` has its own implementation of `>>=` which defines the context that it represents. For lists, the definition is

```
(xs >>= f) = (concat (map f xs))
```

You may want to learn about `Functor` and `Applicative` operations, which are related to the idea of `Monad`, and might help clear some confusion.